# CSS Position property working differently in Firefox

Tags: html, css, image, firefox, position

I've an image that is responding differently to the position attribute in Firefox vs Chrome and IE11.

Check out the draft at http://breezylabs.com/fvba/
Notice the bottom tip of "Fountain Valley" is mis-positioned in Firefox.  It's up at the top of the page, whereas it's in it's correct position in Chrome/IE11.

Here is the code regarding the issue.  The parent is 'relative' while the child (image) is 'absolute'.

```
<td width="1019" height="222" colspan="7" bgcolor="#D6D6DD" style="position:relative;">
<img src="/images/MAIN-CONTENT.png" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; z-index:99;">
```

Also note in the Firefox version the top is cut off of the entire page.  Not sure what's going on here but I've ran out of options.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=firefox+absolute+table+cell

Answer (score 0):

TD is not a block element. Add to the td style:

```
display:block
```

Comment: Sure, it's not a block element, but I don't think destroying the layout of the table is the right way to address it.

Comment: CBroe's search he posted had several suggestions (I didn't think to search for table cell, I was just searching parent).
I tried the display:block but to no avail.  I read somewhere that if there's a colspan or rowspan (which there is) it will not work - and it didn't.

Comment: Even wrapping it in another DIV doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

```
<td width="1019" height="222" colspan="7" bgcolor="#D6D6DD">
<div style="position:relative;">
<img src="/images/MAIN-CONTENT.png" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; z-index:99; float:left;">
</div>
```

I mentioned in a comment earlier that the div method didn't work, but it turns out that the DIV had to be only around the image, not around anything else.